# Regarding Android SDK r20

Tags: android, sdk

basically am a beginner to Android programming and trying to explore it with the help of tutorials available from the net. My question here is for a beginner like me is it well enough if i start leaning with SDK r20 because all the tutorials i find have the previous version of the SDK, and also is that necessary we keep on developing apps based on latest SDK available from the Android?

Comment: Hey friend, older tutorial also works with newer SDK, and if you have newer SDK then why you have to think about using older SDK. Just stay Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can look at the changelog of the new ADT(v 20).:
http://tools.android.com/download/adt-20-preview
As you can see there are just improvements and using this to learn from older tutorials shouldnt be different. So yes you can use it :)

Comment: Thank You Ahmad it was quite helpful :)

Comment: No problem. Thats what SO is for  :)

Answer (score 1):

Ya just stay updated is all ! Doesnt make much of a difference to new programmers